# Set dynamic image to ListView in android custom adapter

Tags: java, android

i am building a listview with items from web server. I got all the items with JSON, i am able to load all the text values to the list view, but i can't assign the image to the list item. when i access a static image from drawable folder it works. Here is my code. I have the image with Base64 and direct file URL.

```
            int[] listviewImage = new int[]{R.drawable.food};
            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray foods= reader.getJSONArray("foods");
            List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for(int i = 0;i<foods.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj_foods = foods.getJSONObject(i);
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(obj_foods .getString("photo_hex"), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

                hm.put("listview_image", Integer.toString(listviewImage[0]));
                hm.put("food_name", obj_foods .getString("food_name"));
                hm.put("food_description",obj_foods .getString("food_description"));
                hm.put("price",obj_foods .getString("price"));
                hm.put("restaurant",obj_foods .getString("restaurant"));

                aList.add(hm);

            }
            String[] from = {"listview_image", "food_name", "food_description","price","restaurant"};
            int[] to = {R.id.listview_image, R.id.listview_item_title, R.id.listview_item_short_description,R.id.price,R.id.restaurant};

            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.food_list, from, to);
            final ListView androidListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            androidListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso to fetch images from online to your app

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: How do i use the obtained image in my context above?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: i fetch the image wit picasso, then how do i add it in my above list view of hash map?

Comment: save it as, hm.put("listview_image", "Image_url");